# 2018 год шифрование

Tags: php, безопасность, шифрование, хеширование

Необходимо зашифровать пароль.
Какие способы и методы шифровки пароля актуальны на данный момент?
А то слышал что md5 в два счета расшифровывается.
Язык PHP.

Comment: в 5.5 появилось нативное API http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.password.php

Comment: Оно безопасно ? А то мне нужен надежный способ

Comment: Ну её и создали специально, чтоб не изобретали велосипеды и не юзали старые md5, а чтоб юзали и не парились... так что да.

Comment: Пароль не шифруют, пароль хэшируют. Пароль по md5 не расшифровывают, его просто подбирают.

Comment: @ДенисХромов это API использует BCrypt, что является общепринятым и лучшим способом для хэширования паролей (так говорят). Чуть более подробно можно на том же хабре прочитать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский уже давно говорят, что Argon2 лучше всех, а bcrypt типа устарел)

Comment: @andreymal как бы то ни было в этом самом API можно задать алгоритм как PASSWORD_ARGON2I  так и PASSWORD_BCRYPT. Так что кто как хотИт))

Comment: `7.2.0  Добавлена поддержка хеширующего алгоритма Argon2 с помощью PASSWORD_ARGON2I.`